# Given points A(0,0) and B(10, 0) and a distance d = 15 find the shortest arc between the two.

Tags: curves, arc-length, path-connected, fixed-points

I'm trying to find an arc between two points that maps a path between them given some set distance. I'm not a math major so pardon if I make some inaccurate statements below. I'm trying to figure out the movement of a robot.

I have point A(0,0) and point B(10, 0). The shortest path would simply be a straight line of distance 10. However, I know the given distance travelled is 15. Therefore, I assume there exists a way to determine the shortest arc between the two points (in the positive xy-axis). Perhaps the word arc may be misleading. It can be any path from point A to point B as long as the path is of the given length 15. Is there a way to find an equation for the domain of possible paths?

Any ideas would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So let me phrase it differently. You want to find the circle arc between $(0,0)$ and $(10,0)$ such that the length of the arc between those two points is $15$.

This is something you could do:
The equation of a circle with center in $(a,b)$ (not to be confused with your points $A,B$) and radius $R$
$$
(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2
$$
In particular, your points have to satisfy this equation, i.e. if I replace $x=0,y=0$ and $x=10,y=0$ the equation holds. That gives you that $a=5$, and $a^2+b^2=R^2$

Now to impose the length condition note that the length of your path is $R\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle traveled, so you want to impose:
$$
R\theta =15
$$

To recapitulate we have the two equations
$$
R\theta=15\\
5^2+b^2=R^2
$$
To solve for the three variables $b,R,\theta$. The equation we are missing simply comes from trigonometry. It gives:
$$
\sin (\theta/2)=5/R
$$
(I could make a drawing if you don't see it, but I encourage to try to get it by yourself).

You can now solve for $b,R$ to get the equation of the circle.

Comment: So to then solve for b, R I would get $R = 5/sin(theta/2)$? And then to get be I just square R and plug that into the original equation? Also I unfortunately do not see how you go from $Rtheta = 15$ to $sin(theta/2)=5/R$. I get that $sin(a/c)$ but wouldn't a be 5 and c be R? Ergo $sine(5/R)$. Where does the 2 and theta come from.